# SAML setup assertion with custom parameters

Tags: onelogin

I have working SAML 2.0 in my dev account https://espatialzdenek-dev.onelogin.com

I am able to login through onelogin.

Only problem I have is that I can't change / I don't know how to change attribute names in the login request from IDP to SP.

in the assertion saml response I get in section

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
```

for example this element

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
     <saml:Attribute Name="User.FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">z2</saml:AttributeValue>
     </saml:Attribute>
```

but I need there

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
     <saml:Attribute Name="firstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">z2</saml:AttributeValue>
     </saml:Attribute>
```

I need make this change at least for first name , last name and user assigned security groups.

Is there way to do this in oneLogin SAML IDP setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add App -> SAML Test.....

That will give you a custom application with all options available to you. Create custom claims to your hearts content.

Comment: Thanks. I am using SAML Test Connector (IdP w/ attr w/ sign response). I could add there parameter, but how could I define value of the attribute? So far I was able to put there just constants. I would like to set there same attribute value as User.FirstName.

Comment: interesting, I have created another idp and there is dropdown when I try define custom attribute. First idp I have created allow me to set only value and there is no dropdown ...

Comment: The different SAML Test apps provide different capabilities. Use the SAML Test Advanced to get the most flexibilty and you should be able to do what you need.